# Easiest way to increment a data point in Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble incrementing a piece of data in Firebase.

```
Firebase {
    clickedCounter: 0
}
```

This is my code:

```
@IBAction func plus(sender: UIButton) {
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("clickedCounter").observeEventType(.Value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
            let value = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("clickedCounter") as? NSNumber
            let increment = ((value?.intValue)! + ((1 as? NSNumber)?.intValue)!) as? NSNumber
            FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("clickedCounter").setValue()
            self.clickLabel.text = snap.value?.description as String!
        }
    }
```

I also tried:

```
@IBAction func plus(sender: UIButton) {
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("clickedCounter").observeEventType(.Value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
            FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("clickedCounter").setValue((snap.value?.description)! + 1)
            self.clickedLabel.text = snap.value?.description as! String!
        }
    }
```

For my first my warnings are:

`Cast from Int32 to NSNumber always fails`

`Conditional cast from NSNumber to NSNumber always succeeds`

`Cast from FIRDatabaseReference to NSNumber always fails`

After I ran it, I got the error on `let increment....` : `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`

For my second the error is:

`Binary operator + cannot be applied to operands of the type String and Int`

1. I'm confused as to how my `snap.value?.description` is a String when I thought I defined it in Firebase as an Int.
2. Why do I get a warning when something always succeeds?
3. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not (v2.x Firebase code but you get the idea)

```
counterRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
     let valString = snapshot.value
     var value = valString.intValue
     value = value + 1
     counterRef.setValue("\(value)")         
})
```

If this is going to be updated frequently by multiple users, leverage a transaction block as well.

Comment: This works, thank you. One more question though. When I clicked the plus, the action kept on running, making the number +1 over and over again. Do you know a fix?

Comment: Actually, sorry I had not implemented your code fully. What is the difference between observeSingleEventOfType and observeEventType? When should I use either?

Comment: observeSingleEventOfType reads a node once whereas observeEventType attaches an observer to that node. It notifies the app once, and then continually monitors changes (add, change, remove) and notifies the application of those changes when they occur. See the Firebase guide [Retrieve Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data) for details. Generally, if you just want a piece of data and don't need to know if it changes, use observeSingleEventOfType, as in this use case. If you want to know about changes, like in a chat type application, use observeEventType

Comment: If you have data persistence turned on - this kind of increment won't be reliable at all. If the counter is changed from somewhere else - this one-time observer will keep returning old value. The old (cached) value will be returned long time after the real value has been changed.

Comment: @Vitalii Not sure what that means - obviously if an app relies on *current data* you wouldn't have persistence turned on as then *any* data would be stale when being read from cache, right? For example, if an app is showing geo location data and the user goes through a long tunnel, they  wouldn't want it to keep displaying incorrect data for a location they were 10 minutes ago. The app should indicate 'location data is not available' in that case.

Comment: @Jay, not exactly. An app that relies on current data might still successfully do this with persistence turned on, it can be both: offline-first and fully reactive altogether. Therefore I've added a disclaimer to everyone who has enabled persistence in their apps that they should never rely on `observeSingleEvent`. For apps with persistence turned off this answer is great.

Answer (score 5):

Try using transactions to safely get the current data and increment it. 
See the example in the docs here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data#receive_a_completion_callback

Comment: Thats the web version of it, I couldn't find the swift version.

Answer (score 0):

If the database has persistence turned OFF, follow @Jay's answer.

But **if your database has persistence turned ON**, the usual way to increment with `observeSingleEventOfType` won't work at all - it will increment based on old value and will mess everything in the end.

Luckily, thanks to the findings made by Natural Lam described in his article [here](https://medium.com/@naturallam/firebase-data-out-of-sync-during-initial-fetch-6e20b7a7c7b9), there is still a way to reliably increment in case of persistence turned on. The trick is in forcing Firebase to sync data by a combination of `keepSynced` and a write operation. Here's an example how it works for me:

```
func increaseUnreadChatsFor(chatId: String) {
    let chatRef = self.ref.child("chats/\(chatId)")
    chatRef.keepSynced(true)
    chatRef.child("dummy").setValue("dummy") { _, _ in
        chatRef.child("dummy").removeValue()
        chatRef.keepSynced(false)
        chatRef.child("unread").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
             if !snapshot.exists() { // no unread record yet, creating one
                chatRef.child("unread").setValue(1)
             } else if let unread = snapshot.value as? Int { // record already exists, incrementing it
                chatRef.child("unread").setValue(unread + 1)
             }
         })
    }
}
```

Of course it is not guaranteed to work in offline.

Another alternative would be to configure same database once again, but this time with persistence turned OFF and do the increment using that firebase instance (which will obviously work only in online). How to do this you can read in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59722159/2650588).