# How can I do an offline batch in Firebase RTDB?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, offline

I have reason to believe that some `ServerValue.increment()` commands are not executing.

In my App, when the user submits, two commands are executed:

```
Future<void> _submit() async {
    alimentoBloc.descontarAlimento(foodId, quantity);
    salidaAlimentoBloc.crearSalidaAlimento(salidaAlimento);
}
```

The first command updates the amount of inventory left in the warehouse (using ServerValue.increment)...

```
 Future<bool> descontarAlimento(String foodId, int quantity) async {
    try {
      dbRef.child('inventory/$foodId/quantity')
        .set(ServerValue.increment(-quantity));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
   return true;
  }
```

The second command makes a food output register, where it records the quantity, type of food and other key data.

```
  Future<bool> crearSalidaAlimento(SalidaAlimentoModel salidaAlimento) async {

    try {
      dbRef.child('output')
        .push().set(salidaAlimento.toJson());
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return true;
  }
```

After several reviews, I have noticed that the increase command is not executed sometimes, and then the inventory does not correspond to what it should be.

Then, I would like to do something similar to a transaction, this is: If neither of the two commands is executed, do not execute either of the two.

**Is it possible to do a batch of commands in Firebase Realtime without losing the offline functionalities?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do a multi-path update to perform both writes transactionally:

```
var id = dbRef.push().key;
Map<String, dynamic> updates = {
  "inventory/$foodId/quantity": ServerValue.increment(-quantity),
  "output/$id": salidaAlimento.toJson()
}
dbRef.update(updates);
```

With the above, either both writes are completed, or neither of them is.

While you're offline, the client will fire local events based on its best guess for the current value of the server (which is gonna be `0` if it never read the value), and it will then send all pending changes to the server when it reconnects. For a quick test, see https://jsbin.com/wuhuyih/2/edit?js,console

Comment: Thank you @puf. It looks promising. How do I write in the Database? Something like `dbRef.child(''). update(updates)`or `dbRef.child(''). set(updates)` ?

Comment: Oh right, forgot to add that as I was focused on getting the map right. :) I added the statement now, so that all paths are evaluated against `dbRef`.

Comment: @puf. I'm testing and it looks like a great solution. I don't know why, but when I use `.set` my app crashes... the error in console is _Lost connection to device. Exited (sigterm)_. When I use `.update`, the function seems to work fine.

Comment: Uhm... good catch, that should actually have been a call to `update()`, as otherwise you'll end up **replacing** all other data at `dbRef` instead of just updating the two affected nodes. My guess is that the top-level write gets rejected by your security rules, which would be a Good Thing in this case. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `transaction` while the device is offline.
They need to check the current value on the database and that is not possible while offline. If you want to make sure that they succeed you would need to check if a connection is awailable or not.

Comment: Thank you Tarik. Any other idea? The reason I use ServerValue.Increment () is precisely because my users are offline some of the time. This way, when they come back online, the function is executed atomically.

Comment: Maybe this here helps more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58359065/5519300

Comment: Doug's answer was before ServerValue.increment() was published. Please see the [link](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2437)

Comment: Hey Tarik, `ServerValue.increment` works fine while offline as far as I know. Also see the link in my answer for a quick test best

Comment: Ah cool. Haven't noticed that. Thx Puff :)